# MediaPlayer - java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider

Tags: java, android, exception, android-mediaplayer

I've been writing an mp3 player for quite some time, but for some reason this exception:

> W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open /storage/emulated/0/Music/generic music
>   file.mp3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Music/generic music file.mp3

keeps popping up every time I try to play **any** song.

The way I retrieve path to a song is:

```
file.getAbsolutePath()
```

where *file* is a File instance. And the way I play the song is:

```
try {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(currentTrack.getPath()));
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            nextTrack();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

where *this* is a reference to an instance of a class, which extends *Service*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running Nougat or higher on your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, `currentTrack` has a `File` object. If so, replace `Uri.parse(currentTrack.getPath())` with `currentTrack.getUri()`, where you implement `getUri()` to return the value of `Uri.fromFile()` for the `File`.

This solves your immediate problem, which is that you have created an invalid `Uri`, as it has no scheme. It also sets you up to deal with `Uri` types that are not files (e.g., `content` `Uri` values) that you may wind up needing in the future.

Comment: What does one do if one is starting out with only a file path? Why would one have to implement `getUri` when from your comment it seems one could use `Uri.fromFile(new File(path))` ? I don't find this a good answer. I could think of 10 other questions that your comment raises.

Comment: What about if your method only takes a File? I dont need uri, i need file.

Comment: @EzequielAdrian: Rewrite the method to use an `InputStream` or a `Uri`. If the method is from a library, see if there is a newer version of the library that offers more flexibility, or find a replacement library.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs in Nougat or higher version if you are using nougat or higher version you have to use `Content Provider`.

Create an XML file (for example file_provider_paths.xml) in XML resources folder:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="shared" path="shared/"/>
</paths>
```

Now define a provider in your ApplicationManifest.xml, add this provider inside application node:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="<your provider authority>" //com.domainname.appname.fileprovider
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Now get the shared file URI, and use it in your application where you need it.

```
Uri sharedFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, <your provider auhtority>, sharedFile);
```

Comment: You need to implement this only if you are passing Uri to third party app Activity