# How do I retrieve an image from Firebase Storage and show it? Getting "No content provider" error

Tags: android-imageview, firebase-storage, android-contentresolver

My app is saving images in Firebase Storage, but I'm having trouble retrieving and viewing them. Images are uploaded fine, into a folder called "images".

Each image is associated with a `Box`. The `boxes` collection in the database looks like this:

```
boxes > key1 > name: Box 1 name
             > uid: xxxxxxxxx          (user id of Box creator)
             > image: "images/box1image.jpg"
      > key2 > name: Box 2 name
             > uid: yyyyyyyyy          
             > image: "images/box2image.jpg"
```

I want to retrieve the image and show it in a DialogFragment.  Currently the fragment layout (`dialog_fragment_show_box`) looks like this (I've taken out layout_width etc for brevity):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_box_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_box_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_box_image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, when the DialogFragment loads, I want to pass in the `Box`, and display its name and associated image.  `Box.java` contains:

```
public class HybridBox {

    private String  name, uid, key, url;


    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public HybridBox() {}

    // GETTERS
    public String   getName()         { return name; }
    public String   getUrl()          { return url; }
    public String   getUid()          { return this.uid; }
    public String   getKey()          { return key; }

    // SETTERS
    public void setName(String thisName) { this.name = thisName; }
    public void setUrl(String thisUrl)   { this.url = thisUrl; }
    public void setUid(String thisUid)   { this.uid = thisUid; }
    public void setKey(String thisKey)   { this.key = thisKey; }

}
```

The `Box` is retrieved from the database with no problems, and passed into the DialogFragment, which is:

```
public class DialogFragmentShowBox extends DialogFragment {

    private Context         mContext;
    private EditText        mBoxName;
    private ImageView       mBoxImage;
    private HybridBox       mBox;

    public DialogFragmentShowBox() {}

    public static DialogFragmentShowBox newInstance() {
        return new DialogFragmentShowBox();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.dialog_fragment_show_box, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBoxImage        = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_box_image);
        mBoxName         = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_box_name);

        show_details();
        draw_iv();

    }

    // Pass in Box object
    public void setBox(HybridBox box) {

        mBox = box;

        show_details();
        draw_iv();

    }

    // Set up Context
    public void setContext(Context context) { mContext = context; }

    // Show details of the Box (currently just name)
    private void show_details() {

        if(mBox == null) return;

        if(mBoxName != null) {
            mBoxName(mBox.getName());
        }
    }

    // Draw the Box image
    private void draw_iv() {
        if(mBox == null) return;

        if(mBoxImage != null) {

            FirebaseStorage mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            final StorageReference mStorageRef = mStorage.getReference();

            final String drawableUrl = mBox.getUrl();

            if(drawableUrl != null) {
                mStorageRef.child(mBox.getUrl())
                           .getDownloadUrl()
                           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        // Got the download URL
                        ContentResolver res = mContext.getContentResolver();
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap
                                    = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    res,
                                    uri);
                            mBoxImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following warning, and the Box Image is blank:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tickybox-d8888.appspot.com/o/images%2F561e1408-3b17-4eaa-b0ff-d3b00479d1c0.jpg?alt=media&token=9656ea28-2493-447b-aa30-9dbc4c39b3fc
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1396)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1247)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:967)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:888)
        at sharongilmore.tickybox.fragments.dialogFragments.DialogFragmentShowBox$6.onSuccess(DialogFragmentShowBox.java:295)
W/System.err:     at sharongilmore.tickybox.fragments.dialogFragments.DialogFragmentShowBox$6.onSuccess(DialogFragmentShowBox.java:288)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The uri being passed into the success listener is in the form:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tickybox-d8888.appspot.com/o/images%2F561e1408-3b17-4eaa-b0ff-d3b00479d1c0.jpg?alt=media&token=9656ea28-2493-447b-aa30-9dbc4c39b3fc
```

(I've changed some of the url to post here, but when I go to it in a browser it shows the correct image so I think it's ok).

The `ContentResolver` `res` is populated; not sure what it's meant to be, but in the variable list in the debugger the first line is:

```
res = {ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@8456}
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this as follows:

```
FirebaseStorage mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
final StorageReference mStorageRef = mStorage.getReference();

mStorageRef.child(mBox.getUrl()).getDownloadUrl()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {                           
             Glide.with(getContext()).load(uri).into(mBoxImage);
         }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
         @Override
         public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
             // Handle any errors
         }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081044/10540038) can help your situation brother!

Presumably, `currentTrack` has a `File` object. If so, replace `Uri.parse(currentTrack.getPath())` with `currentTrack.getUri()`, where you implement getUri() to return the value of `Uri.fromFile()` for the `File`.

This solves your immediate problem, which is that you have created an invalid Uri, as it has no scheme. It also sets you up to deal with `Uri` types that are not files (e.g., `content` `Uri` values) that you may wind up needing in the future.

Copied!

Comment: Thanks - I'm currently working on something else, but I'll check this out when I can!

Comment: Please check the answer, in case it helps you!